# Not printing occurrences of each keys correctly with the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to print how many times a particular Key has occurred in an array and it seems like it's printing one for all of the values. Could anyone please tell me what logical error I am having in the code below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MostOccuranceOfNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] n = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7};

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        // Create Hash Map

        for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++){


            if(map.containsKey(n)){

                map.put(n[i], map.get(n[i]) +1);

            }
            else{

                map.put(n[i], 1);
            }

            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> m : map.entrySet()){

                System.out.println("Key "+m.getKey()+"Occured"+m.getValue()+"times");

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you nest one loop within the other?

Comment: You're iterating over every element, that means one iteration for each occurrence of `7` so it will print out the count every time. You want to get a a set that contains only unique values, and then iterate over that set while consulting the original set for the counts.

Comment: Oh, Nesting one loop within the other is the logical error I didn't realize but pasting it outside the for loop is again printing each keys values as 1 only

Comment: `if(map.containsKey(n)` doesn't make sense. `n` is an array.

Comment: @John Are you using an IDE? You should really get a suspicious method call warning on that line.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes, I am using Eclipse . Didn't see any warning though.

Comment: I use IntelliJ not eclipse so I can't be sure, but I suspect you can change settings to get helpful warnings for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MostOccuranceOfNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] n = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7};

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

    // Create Hash Map

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++){


        if(map.containsKey(n[i])){//you made mistake here

            map.put(n[i], map.get(n[i]) +1);

        }
        else{

            map.put(n[i], 1);
        }



    }

     }
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> m : map.entrySet()){

            System.out.println("Key  "+m.getKey()+"Occured "+m.getValue()+" times ");//Sorry forgot to take it outside


 }

}
```

Comment: You've still got the second `for` loop inside the first.